# How to select div inside div using non tagged text using XPath?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I want to select div with class=membername using xpath with "Laura" as a parameter.

```
<div class="label">
  <div class="membername"></div>
  David
</div>
<div class="label">
  <div class="membername"></div>
  Laura
</div>
```

This is what I have so far for the XPath:

```
//div[@class='label']/div[@class='membername']
```

What comes next after that?

EDIT:
I forgot to specify that the set of div class="label" is dynamic. So there's chance that there will be 5 set of div class="label" and div class="green" will not be the second element with class = membername.

Answer (score 1):

**The element is the second one in the indentified list so use the locator:**

```
(//div[@class="membername"])[2]
```

**so you can use it code as :**

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="membername"])[2]').text)
```

**Update:**

laura is not in the div `//div[@class="membername"]`  it is a text node of `//div[@class="label"]`

```
 //div[text()[contains(.,"Laura")]]
```

if you just need member element then use:

```
//div[text()[contains(.,"Laura")]]/div[@class="membername"]
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that the number of <div class="label"> is dynamic. So the number of element is not known.

Comment: @user3005 so what are you searching in it the name Laura ?

Comment: I edited my original question. Did not notice the html tags in my question did not show properly.

Comment: //div[@class='label']/div[@class='membername' and contains(text(),"Laura")]

Comment: This will give the whole div from class=label. I only need to get the div with class= membername

Comment: @user3005 why you need that element ?

Comment: @user3005 use `//div[text()[contains(.,"Laura")]]/div[@class="membername"]`

Comment: but that element doesn't have anything inside it

Comment: membername is class for button that is clickable that's why I need it. So basically I need to click the button based on the parameter Laura.

Comment: added the answer

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign